# How does the website "minutesplease.com" close tab in my chrome window?

Tags: google-chrome, tabs, web

The website "http://minutesplease.com/" does something I thought was impossible - it closes a tab in my chrome (also without my permission!).

How is it possible for a website (not extension) to close a tab in my chrome window? Up to this moment I was conviced the most a website can do is stop to supply me with packets. In which case I will only get a connection error, not a tab termination. Also, not only did it close a tab, it closed a tab that wasn't his own (!). The only connection between this website and the tab is that it was responsible to open it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source code is located in this single javascript file => [misc.js](http://minutesplease.com/misc.js)

The site is opening up new sites as Popups, and then closing the Popups using Javascript in the following function.

```
        function killIt(i)
        {
            if(!popupWindow[i].closed) popupWindow[i].close();
            stopCountDown(i);
        }
```

So it's not a window, just make it look like a window :)

See the function `popSite()` (pasted below) to understand how it opens up new urls as Popups.

```
      function popSite()
        {
            var url = fixUrl(document.getElementById("url").value);
            var operaError = "In order to use this feature, you must allow popups for this site.  Simply unblocking a blocked-popup will not do.";

            try
            {
                var newWindow = window.open(url);
                if (newWindow == null )
                {
                    alert("In order to use this feature, you must allow popups for this site.");
                    return;
                }
                if (window.opera)
                    if (!newWindow.opera)
                    {
                        alert(operaError);
                        return;
                    }
            }
            catch(err)
            {
                //This is here to account for inexplicable behavior in opera
            }

            nOpenWindows++;
            if(nOpenWindows == 1) updateInterval = setInterval("updateTime()",100);
            newWindow.focus();
            nWindows = popupWindow.push(newWindow);
            var index = nWindows - 1;

            alive[index] = true;
            timeRequest[index] = toMilliseconds(document.getElementById("time").value);

            var d = new Date();
            popStart[index] = d.getTime();

            //Create a new entry in the table of timed sites.
            var templateCopy = document.getElementById("templateRow").cloneNode(true);
            provideIds(templateCopy,index);

            document.getElementById("siteList").appendChild(templateCopy);

            if(removePrefix(url) =="") windowURL[index] = "BLANK"; else windowURL[index] = removePrefix(url).toUpperCase();

            var siteLink = document.getElementById("site"+index);
            siteLink.innerHTML = windowURL[index];

            if (timeRequest[index] <= warningTime()) haveWarned[index] = 1; else haveWarned[index] = 0;

            pauseTime[index] = 0;

            alertWindow[index] = null;

            alertWindowTimeout[index] = null;

            //Now display it
            templateCopy.style.display = "";

            addToActiveList(index);
        }
```

and here's the code that "kills" the window (i.e. the Popup)

```
        function killIt(i)
        {
            if(!popupWindow[i].closed) popupWindow[i].close();
            stopCountDown(i);
        }
```

Comment: Whaa... So you say pop-ups aren't only these annoying alert() windows with little text but can also be tabs for them selves with an actual website inside? Incredible. First time I ever encounter something like this.